# Android VideoView GStreamer Streaming(MediaController doesn't work )

Tags: android, gstreamer, android-videoview, rtsp, mediacontroller

I have some small project to stream video to android device. Streaming is done but I have problem with controlling video. The MediaController doesn't work when I push pause there is no effect. VideoView.pause() also doesn't work. Streaming server is based on GStreamer (server was wrote by my friend), and I'am using Android 2.2 CyanogenMod.

This is server code :

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstRTSPServer *server;
  GstRTSPMediaMapping *mapping;
  GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;
  gchar *str;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  if (argc < 2) {
    g_message ("usage: %s <filename>", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  /* create a server instance */
  server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();

  /* get the mapping for this server, every server has a default mapper object
   * that be used to map uri mount points to media factories */
  mapping = gst_rtsp_server_get_media_mapping (server);

  str = g_strdup_printf ("( "
       "filesrc location=\"%s\" ! decodebin2 name=d "
       "d. ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=500, height=300 "
       "! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay name=pay0 "
       "d. ! queue ! audioconvert ! faac ! rtpmp4apay name=pay1"
       " )", argv[1]);

  /* make a media factory for a test stream. The default media factory can use
   * gst-launch syntax to create pipelines. 
   * any launch line works as long as it contains elements named pay%d. Each
   * element with pay%d names will be a stream */
  factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, str);
  g_free (str);

  /* attach the test factory to the /test url */
  gst_rtsp_media_mapping_add_factory (mapping, "/test", factory);

  /* don't need the ref to the mapper anymore */
  g_object_unref (mapping);

  /* attach the server to the default maincontext */
  gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL);

  /* start serving */
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have gathered, the `VideoView` in android only accepts `h.264` feeds so you need to be encoding in `h.264`.